# Upper bound on Trigamma function $\psi^{(1)}(x)$ for $x\in\Bbb N$

Tags: inequality, gamma-function

> The Trigamma function is defined as $\psi^{(1)}(x):=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dx^2} \ln (\Gamma(x))$, where $\Gamma(x)$ is the Gamma function. I am trying to find an upper bound for this function where $x\in \mathbb{Z}, x>0$.

I'm looking at [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) on Digamma function and see that $\psi^{(0)}(x)=\frac{d}{dx} \ln (\Gamma(x))= \frac{\Gamma'(x)}{\Gamma(x)}\sim \ln x-\frac{1}{2x} $. If I go with the approximation of Digamma function, then $\psi^{(1)}(x)=\frac{d}{dx^2} \ln (\Gamma(x)) \sim \frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}<\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$. But I'm wondering if there is a known upper bound or if we can show that $\psi^{(1)}(x)<\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$ for all $x\in \mathbb{Z},x>0$?

Comment: Do you mean the upper bound as the maximum of the function, if so then the upper bound is at infinity. For the lower bound/ minimum, just use the classic first derivative test.

Comment: @TymaGaidash I should have stated $x\in \mathbb{Z}$. Editing that now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you are looking on the wrong wiki page @manifolded. Moving over the the wiki page for the [polygamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygamma_function#Inequalities), $\psi^{(m)}(x):=\partial_x^{m+1}\log\Gamma(x)$, we find the following inequality:

> For all $m\geq 1$ and $x > 0$,
>
> $$
> \frac{(m-1)!}{x^m}+\frac{m!}{2x^{m+1}}\leq(-1)^{m+1}\psi^{(m)}(x)\leq\frac{(m-1)!}{x^m}+\frac{m!}{x^{m+1}}.
> $$

You can find on this page details about the proof of this inequality too. For the specific case of the trigamma function, $m=1$; hence,
$$
\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2x^2}\leq\psi^{(1)}(x)\leq\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2},
$$
which is precisely the bounds you derived! Note that these bounds hold for all $x>0$ so that the additional requirement $x\in\Bbb Z$ is automatically satisfied.

Answer (score 3):

It follows from Theorem 1.3 of the paper https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2017.0363 that for any $N\geq 1$ and $x>0$,
$$
\psi ^{(1)} (x) = \zeta (2,x) = \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{2x^2 }} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{{B_{2n} }}{{x^{2n + 1} }}}  + \theta _N (x)\frac{{B_{2N} }}{{x^{2N + 1} }}
$$
where $B_n$ denotes the Bernoulli numbers and $0<\theta _N (x)<1$ is a suitable number depending on $N$ and $x$. (Empy sums are interpreted as zero.) In particular,
$$
\frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{2x^2 }} < \psi ^{(1)} (x) < \frac{1}{x} + \frac{1}{{2x^2 }} + \frac{1}{{6x^3 }}$$
for any $x>0$.

Comment: (+1) for the interesting reference.

Answer (score 2):

If you use the series expansion
$$\psi ^{(1)}(x)=\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{6 x^3}-\frac{1}{30 x^5}+\frac{1}{42
   x^7}-\frac{1}{30 x^9}+\frac{5}{66
   x^{11}}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^{13}}\right)$$ you have simple bounds such
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{6 x^3}-\frac{1}{30 x^5}<\psi ^{(1)}(x)<\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2 x^2}+\frac{1}{6 x^3}$$

Comment: Why do those estimates hold? Is it an alternating series whose terms decrease in absolute value?

Comment: The series is divergent, but these estimates will hold for another reason. You may represent $\psi^{(1)}$ in terms of the Hurwitz zeta function and then use Theorem 1.3 of the paper https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.2017.0363

Answer (score 0):

https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.1984 has a tighter bound:

$$
\frac{(k-1)!}{\Bigl\{x+\Bigl[\frac{(k-1)!}{|\psi^{(k)}(1)|}\Bigr]^{1/k}\Bigr\}^k} +\frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}<\bigl|\psi^{(k)}(x)\bigr|<\frac{(k-1)!}{\bigl(x+\frac12\bigr)^k}+\frac{k!}{x^{k+1}}
$$

Or, for the particular case of $\psi^{(1)}$:

$$
\frac{1}{x+\frac{6}{\pi^2}} +\frac{1}{x^{2}}<\psi^{(1)}(x)<\frac{1}{x+\frac12}+\frac{1}{x^{2}}
$$